# Non navigational options SideBar

Tags: android

Hi i was wondering if it was possible to create a Sidebar for an activity that would allow a user to select a few options such as extra information that can be associated with an object. before sending it off to a server through an API I have looked at trying to use Googles own Nav bar as well as a few Third party libraries that dont seem to want to work for me.

Encase you dont understand what im trying to achieve ill give an example:

Say i have an activity that allows the user to create a log for a specific group within the app now the user may press submit and it will be sent off to the server to be stored in a Database but the user can also associate other aspects to this log such as a book id or an activity ID.

So the user should able to pull a side bar from the side and select any extra information they need (probably from spinners or extendable listview) and then go back to the main activity and submit the log.

Is there anyway of creating anything like what im asking with out having to dig into third party libraries?

Answer (score 1):

You can define arbitrary layout for your `NavDrawer` (I will use the name of android component here). There is no enforcement to *navigation* here. So, put in `NavDrawer`'s layout a bunch of controls that you need and define their `onClick`, `onSelected`, etc. methods to handle corresponding properties changing. On submitting just get checked/selected/entered info from controls in `NavDrawer`, augment your data with it and send to server.

Comment: Would I need define the Nav layout in a separate XML file or in the same activity xml file?

Comment: @MarcD the way to create DrawerLayout is desribed [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout). Shortly, your activity layout should have DrawerLayout as root tag with two children inside. First - your main layout, second - side menu. You can define entire side menu layout in activity layout or extract it in a separate file and include in activity layout through `<include>` tag.